# Which Android phone models support getNeighboringCellInfo()?

Tags: android

I want to find a phone that can call getNeighboringCellInfo() without returning null.

I'm owning a LG-P990 and unfortunately it fails.
I have read some articles and find that all Samgsung phones including Nexus S don't work.

Nexus one works, but it's difficult to find one now.
Could anybody tell me which models will work? Thanks.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighbours = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you know if it's the same problem with the Samsung Galaxy S Plus?
Does it work work with the emulator?

Comment: I have one :-) Have you tried any rooted phones?

Comment: My phone is rooted. The problem seems unrelated to rooted or not.

Answer (score 4):

I tried a couple of phone models, and I found out that most of the Samsung phones don't give you this information.

You can get this information from

- Google Nexus One
- HTC Sensation
- Android G1
- HTC Desire

Comment: Just tried Galaxy S4 and it will only provide the cell you are connected to. Pitty...

Answer (score 1):

Also LG Nexus 4 seems to support getNeighboringCellInfo().

Answer (score 0):

HTC One support neighboring cell info as well.