# Is it possible in android to get data of cellular network stat

Tags: android, mobile-devices, cellular-network

Is it possible to get data like radiation of device and cellular tower,
Distance of cellular tower,
And basic details of cellular network from android device programmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668271/get-cell-tower-locations-android   , please  see the post that gets ur cell id

Comment: hi @SatishPathuri  can you describe answer with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get signal strength of the device, what kind of connection it is, etc. with the Telephony api :    [android.telephony.SignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html)

Basic details of the network from ConnectivityManager: [android.net.ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) and [android.net.NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html)

Here is a link to a discussion on getting cell tower information: [Retrieve cell towers information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294545/retrieve-cell-towers-information)

Comment: thank you david,
does signal strength mean by radiation?

Comment: If you read the documentation you'll see that the signal strength is in decibel milliwatts; so yes I would think so.